How should we tag real assets?
As per the 7 essential questions, this question on volatility used a "real" tag.  While I understand that has a clear meaning in economics, as a stand-alone tag it seems like it could be easily confused.
What does everyone think?  Any better choices?

I think you would need to distinguish real estate from real options, since both are available in the quant world. Perhaps changing the tag to specify the asset class would be better.
